# Subtracting a 10% discount from total price

Tags: python-3.x

I am a java programmer playing with python. So, if this seems a little newbieish, that's because it is. Bear with me.

I am trying to Calculate and subtract 10% from the total price of an item. But when I do, it tells me there are datatype mismatches. I know in Java I'd just use nextInt() to differentiate the types from a Scanner, and I tried using Decimal() and int(), but the interpreter is telling me that the type for itemName isn't recognised. I thought python had a Scanner built into the input which could detect the raw string input.

Please help

```
<code>
from decimal import Decimal
itemName = input()
itemPrice = Decimal(input())
itemQuantity = int(input())

if itemQuantity <= 10:
        print(itemQuantity,'x',itemName,'@ $',itemPrice)
        print('Total: $',itemQuantity*itemPrice)
else:
        discountMultplier = 0.1
        print(itemQuantity,'x',itemName,'@ $',itemPrice)
        print('Subtotal: $',itemQuantity*itemPrice)
        print('-10% Discount: $',(itemQuantity*itemPrice)*discountMultiplier)
        print('Total: $',itemQuantity*itemPrice-((itemQuantity*itemPrice)*discountMultiplier))</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you are getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print('-10% Discount: $',(itemQuantity*itemPrice)*discountMultiplier)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

- Please include the error next time

Is because `Decimal` objects (itemPrice) cannot be multiplied by `float` objects (discountMultiplier) as the error message very obviously states.

short solution, make discountMultiplier a Decimal:

```
discountMultplier = Decimal('0.1')
          # ^ you are missing an i here
```

although because of the above mentioned typo I actually got a NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print('-10% Discount: $',(itemQuantity*itemPrice)*discountMultiplier)
NameError: name 'discountMultiplier' is not defined
```

So please give more attention to your error messages because they are quite informative.

Comment: and thank you @hggohh, This answer just brought me up to 2K rep =D